# Android resource linking failed ( error: failed linking references.)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After i add GDPR code to my app in (MainActivity.java) seccion , After i try to rebuild project i get this error :

```
Android resource linking failed
```

C:\Users\jalal\Desktop\codecanyon-20549858-fast-cleaner-battery-saver-with-admob-ads\Main File\Fast Cleaner & Battery Saver\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
C:\Users\jalal\Desktop\codecanyon-20549858-fast-cleaner-battery-saver-with-admob-ads\Main File\Fast Cleaner & Battery Saver\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
C:\Users\jalal\Desktop\codecanyon-20549858-fast-cleaner-battery-saver-with-admob-ads\Main File\Fast Cleaner & Battery Saver\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
error: failed linking references.

I already checked her and i don't found any solution , Thank you

Comment: What's your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: it's : API 25: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error reported:

> values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found

This one (and the next few) are all because these android attributes were only added in API 26 (that's why they're referenced from values-**v26**). You need to update your `compileSdkVersion` to at least 26, although I'd highly recommend updating to the newest API 28.

Edit your app level's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Izabela i upgrade it to 28 , And when i rebuild the project again i get this error :

Comment: You should start a new Question post for that, it's not related to resources anymore.